# Spring Data mongodb hashed index

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I need to index a column in the mongo collection of type String, but with huge value. I am inclined to use the [Hashed Index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-hashed-index/) but couldn't figure out how to mark an index to use hashes in Spring Data - Mongo API.

My current code to create index:

```
mongo.indexOps('mycollection').ensureIndex(new Index().on('names', Sort.Direction.ASC))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is an open request for an annotation that would provide creating hashed indexes. I found this Jira: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1183

I would try to look into solving that via `mongoOperations.indexOps()...`